# Foreach, Cursor or something else?

Tags: sql, foreach, cursor

I am creating a temp table from a query that generates data from SQL functions.  I would like to use this temp table to perform an insert for each row of data from the temp table.  What is the best way to proceed with this?

#tmpTable is as follows (not all columns shown for simplicity):

```
EmpID       WorkHours      HourlyEquivalent     WeekOf
asmith      12             8.94                 12/5/2011
bjones      23.5           12.75                12/5/2011
criley      40             7.89                 12/5/2011
```

The table EmpHours will already be filled in with the employees hours but needs to be updated with their hourly equivalent (calculated from the aforementioned functions).  I want to perform an UPDATE for each employee from the temp table as follows:

```
UPDATE EmpHours
SET HourlyEquivalent
WHERE WeekOf = #tmpTable.WeekOf
    AND EmpID = #tmpTable.EmpID
```

The number of UPDATEs I would need to perform is under 50 if that matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL is much more efficient at doing operations like this in a single command, instead of a row-by-row update.  Even though you don't have very many rows in this scenario, it's still a good habit to take a set based approach instead of using a loop or a cursor.

```
UPDATE e
SET HourlyEquivalent = t.HourlyEquivalent
FROM
    EmpHours e JOIN
    #tmpTable t ON t.WeekOf = e.WeekOf AND t.EmpID = e.EmpID
```

Comment: +1 - Always advise to avoid RBAR techniques (Row By *Agonising* Row)

Answer (score 1):

To `insert` all rows of `#tmpTable` in another table you can do it all in once.
Assuming both tables have the same structure it would be like this:

```
insert into tablename
select EmpID, WorkHours, HourlyEquivalent, WeekOf from #tmpTable
```

---

Like Michael stated, the update is like this:

```
UPDATE e
SET HourlyEquivalent = t.HourlyEquivalent
FROM
    EmpHours e JOIN
    #tmpTable t ON t.WeekOf = e.WeekOf AND t.EmpID = e.EmpID
```